# Update multiple JSON files in Node.js

Tags: php, node.js

**Updated see below**
I am in the process of creating a Mock API in Node.js. I have 3 files located in my apps json folder that the values token, id and session need to be updated all with the same key.

Here is an example of the 3 files. /json/standardsession.json

{ "token": "this needs manual edited value", "session": { "dlt": true, "start": 5280000, "end": 6000000 },

/json/session.json { "token": "this needs to be same value", "id": "this needs to be same value as token", "warning": "", "resident": { "id": 180161922, "resident_id": 264257672, "name": "John doe", "active": true,

},

/json/start.json

{ "code": 5, "error": null, "session": { "session_id": "this needs to be same value", "start_time": "2022-03-22T15:50:42.000Z", "status": 3 } }

How would I write a function that would update all 3 files with my set value in there respective places but not update all the other keys with the same ID like shown in sessions.json file above with the ID field also showing in residents. That doesn't get updated.

Is is possible to make a form that I can input the value into instead of a function that would update all 3 files with me manually inputting the data I want in it?

Both form and function help would be greatly appricated.

Thank you

**Update:**
**After a few changes to code. I now get the following error. My code is posted below.**

undefined:1
[object Object]
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

```
const fs = require("fs")

//provide this function with a dictionary like
//  give it your manual token value
function updateToken(token){
    

      let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('json/standardsession.json');
      let obj = JSON.parse(rawdata);
   
      obj.token = token
    
   
      fs.fileWrite('json/standardsession.json', obj, '')

      let rawdata2 = fs.readFileSync('json/session.json');
      let obj2 = JSON.parse(rawdata2);

      obj2.token = token
      obj2.id = token

      fs.fileWrite('json/session.json', obj, '')


      let rawdata3 = fs.readFileSync('json/start.json');
      let obj3 = JSON.parse(rawdata3);
      
      obj3.session.session_id = token
      
      fs.fileWrite('json/start.json', obj, '')

      
   }
```

Comment: your question is abit unclear. what do you mean by *I would like to modify the keys for automatically by manually inputting the key* in a webap or cli?  in PHP or nodejs?

Answer (score 0):

You most likely want to create a function in your `app.js` code.

Let me know if I have misunderstood your question but this is the function I wrote for you below:

```
const fs = require("fs")

//provide this function with a dictionary like
//  give it your manual token value
function updateToken(token){
    

      let rawdata = fs.readFileSync(../json/standardsession.json);
      let obj = JSON.parse(rawdata);
   
      obj.token = token
    
   
      fs.fileWrite(../json/standardsession.json, obj)

      let rawdata = fs.readFileSync(../json/session.json);
      let obj = JSON.parse(rawdata);

      obj.token = token
      obj.id = token

      fs.fileWrite(../json/session.json, obj)


      let rawdata = fs.readFileSync(../json/start.json);
      let obj = JSON.parse(rawdata);
      
      obj.session.session_id = token
      
      fs.fileWrite(../json/start.json, obj)

      
   }
}
```

Then to call this function to update your JSONs in code.

Write:

```
updateToken('my new token value');
```

Comment: My json files are located in a folder called json. Applying json/filenames still do not update with this function. Can you please explain to me what I need to change, where to place the values I need to change in the function and how do I run it to change the values. Thanks for your time and help

Comment: Is there any errors? Just put the file paths for the JSONs where I have them listed in the function. Then all you need to give to the function to run is a JSON in the format of `{"server": value_to_be, "address": value_to_be}`

Comment: I am going to repost the question so it is better understood. In response to your question. I'm not getting an error but the files dontnseem to be updating either. I am going to be more descriptive in my question.

Comment: You can edit your question instead.

Comment: Look now. Thanks for the help

Comment: I updated my answer with what you are looking for. Please click the upvote button and give me a tick. Thanks :D

Comment: I made some changes to the code you wrote to fix a few errors I had but now Im getting undefined:1
[object Object]
 ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1.  I updated my code in my original question